# Element is null in foreach loop

Tags: groovy, foreach

I have a problem that I can not understand.

There is a for-each loop, and the debugger tells me there are values in the list, but the concrete body-loop says the current element is null.

How can that be?

```
public void test(){
  List cs = ["a"];
  for(String c:cs){
    print c; // but c is null(sais the debugger)! The console shows "null".
  }
}
```

Edit: Another occourence is:

```
 List<StaticSubFoobary> getBackendSubFoobaryList(List<String> electedSubFoobaryIds) {
     List<StaticSubFoobary> subFoobaries = getStaticBackendFoobaryList()?.collect { StaticMainFoobary cat -> cat.backendSortedSubFoobaries }?.flatten()
     List<StaticSubFoobary> electedSubFoobaries = subFoobaries.findAll { it.numericId in electedSubFoobaryIds}
     return electedSubFoobaries
 }
```

Do throw an NPE
But:

```
 List<StaticSubFoobary> getBackendSubFoobaryList(List<String> electedSubFoobaryIds) {
     List<StaticSubFoobary> subFoobaries = getStaticBackendFoobaryList()?.collect { StaticMainFoobary cat -> cat.backendSortedSubFoobaries }?.flatten()
     List<StaticSubFoobary> electedSubFoobaries = []
     for(StaticSubFoobary it:subFoobaries)
         if(it.numericId in electedSubFoobaryIds)
             electedSubFoobaries.add(it)
     return electedSubFoobaries
 }
```

Doesn't!

Comment: Can you please paste the full code where you are initializing the List ?

Comment: @noob *cough* `List cs = ["a"];`

Comment: Is this Java? If not tag it appropriately.

Comment: @sans481 no, it's Groovy

Comment: It happens again. Ill start an bounty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Finally checked out the project again and build it like i always did before.

The problem is gone away, not sure why but it works now!

I just have to copy all my changes to the new workspace and continue development.

Let this workaround be part of experiences.

Answer (score 2):

> but the concrete body-loop says the current element is null

No it doesn't. If you run this code in the Groovy console, the assertion passes:

```
  List cs = ["a"];
  for(String c:cs){
    assert c == 'a'
  }
```

Conversely, if you run this code in the console the assertion fails

```
  List cs = ["a"];
  for(String c:cs){
    assert c == null
  }
```

Which conclusively proves that the first element of the list is "a" and not null

Comment: No it doesn't? Yes it does! The debugger sais "c is null", I edit my question to force the "Yes".

Comment: @PeterRader Don't believe everything IntelliJ tells you. If you're so convinced that `c == null` how do you explain the result of running these code snippets in the Groovy console. I can only explain it by concluding that `c == 'a'`

Comment: But Grails throws an NPE on c.toString(). "print c==null" prints true.

Comment: @PeterRader No it does not. I am guessing that you wrote wrong chunk of code as an example. See this for the results of running code in original question: http://ideone.com/pLvjq

Comment: The complete original code is almoste secret sorry, checkout the screenshot Don removed from my question (http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9376391/revisions).

Comment: @PeterRader Well, how exactly can we help you if your examplary code works perfectly well? If you can't show us the real code, then try to reproduce the problem with a new chunk of code which DOES fail.

Comment: As i said, i am not allowed to post the code! And i cant reproduce the problem. BTW, if i add an "if(c!=null)" its works.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to cast the GroovyString to String could be the problem. Try with a single quoted string literal.